# Get Previous state on react hook not on class

Tags: reactjs, state

How to get previoius state value in react hook?
Here is my code. I used useRef hook also but didnot work.

```
const [ category, setCategory] = useState([]);
 function updateMarkers(data) { 
 let newCategory= []; 
 let {name, age} = data.payload; 
 //Here need to check previous cateogory has same age or not.
 category && category.map((cate, i) => { 
   if (cate.age!== age) { 
     newCategory[i] = data.payload 
   } 
 }) 
}
```

setCategory((prevCategory) => [...prevCategory, ...newCategory]) }

let prevCategory = usePrevious(category);
console.log(' prevcategory', prevCategory);

Comment: const [ category, setCategory] = useState([]);
function updateMarkers(data) {
        let newCategory= [];
        let {name, age} = data.payload;
                 category&& category.map((cate, i) => {
                    if (cate.age!== age) {
                            newCategory[i] = data.payload
                         }
                })
            }
        }
        setCategory((prevCategory) => [...prevCategory, ...newCategory])
    }

Comment: Here I need to check the previous category value with new one

Comment: Please update your code and your problem in question so I can easy read and understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can create `usePrevious` like this:

```
export default function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```

And using:

```
const previousState = usePrevious(state)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can access previous state doing the following

```
setState(prevState => prevState)
```